# xslt group by count is not coming correctly

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I m trying to Group the Course names and get the count of the Open courses. as per the source xml the count should be 3 but i am getting it as 1 . Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc/INT0408"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet" version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs this">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>

    <!--declare global variables here such as delimiter and linefeed-->
    <xsl:variable name="vDelimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed2" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vWrapQuotes" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDateFormat" select="'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDateTimeFormat" select="'[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y0001]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]'"/>

    <!--Root Template-->
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
<!--Create the header record-->
        <xsl:call-template name="header"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry"
            group-by="wd:Associate_group/wd:Associates_location/@wd:Descriptor">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <reportloaddate>
                <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(this:formatDate(current-date()))"/>
            </reportloaddate>
            <storenumber>

                <xsl:value-of
                    select="this:setOutput(wd:Associate_group/wd:Associates_location/@wd:Descriptor)"
                />
            </storenumber>

            <coursenumbername>
                <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(wd:Learning_Content/@wd:Descriptor)"/>

            </coursenumbername>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()"
                group-by="wd:Learning_Content/@wd:Descriptor">
                <totalregistrations>

                    <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput(count(current-group()))"/>

                </totalregistrations>
                <countincomplete>
                    <xsl:variable name="Incompletecount"
                        select="count(wd:Assignment_Status/@wd:Descriptor != 'Completed')"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Incompletecount"/>
                </countincomplete>



            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>


    </xsl:template>



    <!--Header Template-->
    <xsl:template name="header">


        <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput('reportloaddate')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput('storenumber')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput('coursenumbername')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput('totalregistrations')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="this:setOutput('countincomplete')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:function name="this:setOutput">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="this:set-Output($value, false())"/>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="this:set-Output">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="finalValue" as="xs:boolean"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vWrappedValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="
                    if ($vWrapQuotes = false()) then
                        $value
                    else
                        this:wrapQuotes($value)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="
                if ($finalValue = false()) then
                    concat(string($vWrappedValue), $vDelimiter)
                else
                    $vWrappedValue"/>

    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="this:wrapQuotes">
        <xsl:param name="field"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace($field, '&quot;', '&quot;&quot;')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="this:formatDate">
        <xsl:param name="pDateValue"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="
                if (xs:string($pDateValue) = '') then
                    ''
                else
                    format-date(xs:date($pDateValue), $vDateFormat)"/>

    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="this:formatDateTime">
        <xsl:param name="pDateTimeValue"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="
                if ($pDateTimeValue = '') then
                    ''
                else
                    format-dateTime(xs:dateTime($pDateTimeValue), $vDateTimeFormat)"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source xml is

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc/INT0408">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Learning_Content wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b465a8da42a30000</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">MULTI_COURSE_TEMPLATE-6-1</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Content>
        <wd:Assignment_Status wd:Descriptor="Completed">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">a9e125b224f310000c7f604821aa0123</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Assignment_Status_ID">COMPLETED</wd:ID>
        </wd:Assignment_Status>
        <wd:Required>0</wd:Required>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version assigned to PATERSON GUEYE NYA">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc079018b58db345c7e40000</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment>
        <wd:Completion_Moment>2022-07-12T05:00:00.000-07:00</wd:Completion_Moment>
        <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="STFSWE - STAFF SOFTWARE ENGINEER">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01b8bdc90f1c781166ea</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">STFSWE</wd:ID>
        </wd:Job_Profile>
        <wd:Job_Title>STAFF SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Job_Title>
        <wd:Associate_Manager wd:Descriptor="JUBIN JOSEPH">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">84d886702b650179290394d3f63ca203</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">126061787</wd:ID>
        </wd:Associate_Manager>
        <wd:Learning_Record_group>
            <wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record wd:Descriptor="PATERSON GUEYE NYA - PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b58da2edbd790000</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Enrollment_ID">LEARNING_ENROLLMENT-6-1</wd:ID>
            </wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record>
            <wd:Record_Start_Date>2022-07-12T06:54:27-07:00</wd:Record_Start_Date>
        </wd:Learning_Record_group>
        <wd:Associate_group>
            <wd:Associates_location wd:Descriptor="MARIETTA TECHNOLOGY CENTER, MARIETTA - 9119">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ae25e829c2211e5b3</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Location_ID">9119</wd:ID>
            </wd:Associates_location>
            <wd:Associate_ID>132642851</wd:Associate_ID>
            <wd:Legal_First_Name>PATERSON</wd:Legal_First_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Last_Name>GUEYE NYA</wd:Legal_Last_Name>
            <wd:Hire_Date>07/18/2016</wd:Hire_Date>
            <wd:Custom_Org_Dept wd:Descriptor="027 ELECTRICAL/LIGHTING">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01e59a4e80b3221117d0</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
            </wd:Custom_Org_Dept>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Full time">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e083484df07201c3ab266f6339407c00</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Full_time</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Pay_Rate_Type wd:Descriptor="Salary">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ee8dd6d421811a37d</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID">Salary</wd:ID>
            </wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
            <wd:Time_Type_Code>FS</wd:Time_Type_Code>
            <wd:Label_Line_1>STAFF SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Label_Line_1>
            <wd:Active_Status>1</wd:Active_Status>
        </wd:Associate_group>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
            <wd:Learning_Content_Title>PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:Learning_Content_Title>
            <wd:Registration_Status wd:Descriptor="Enrolled">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">cb6902eac8a110002327d007902323af</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Registration_Record_Status_ID">ENROLLED</wd:ID>
            </wd:Registration_Status>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Learning_Content wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b465a8da42a30000</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">MULTI_COURSE_TEMPLATE-6-1</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Content>
        <wd:Assignment_Status wd:Descriptor="Open">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">a9e125b224f310000c6071e412620120</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Assignment_Status_ID">OPEN</wd:ID>
        </wd:Assignment_Status>
        <wd:Required>0</wd:Required>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version assigned to SAI GONEY">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc079018b58dc4d44aa90000</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment>
        <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="SRSFWE - SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01fb2bdcf60a7811b1e7</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">SRSFWE</wd:ID>
        </wd:Job_Profile>
        <wd:Job_Title>SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Job_Title>
        <wd:Associate_Manager wd:Descriptor="JUBIN JOSEPH">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">84d886702b650179290394d3f63ca203</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">126061787</wd:ID>
        </wd:Associate_Manager>
        <wd:Learning_Record_group>
            <wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record wd:Descriptor="SAI GONEY - PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b58dc439763e0001</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Enrollment_ID">LEARNING_ENROLLMENT-6-2</wd:ID>
            </wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record>
            <wd:Record_Start_Date>2022-07-12T06:54:27-07:00</wd:Record_Start_Date>
        </wd:Learning_Record_group>
        <wd:Associate_group>
            <wd:Associates_location wd:Descriptor="MARIETTA TECHNOLOGY CENTER, MARIETTA - 9119">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ae25e829c2211e5b3</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Location_ID">9119</wd:ID>
            </wd:Associates_location>
            <wd:Associate_ID>137358883</wd:Associate_ID>
            <wd:Legal_First_Name>SAI</wd:Legal_First_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Last_Name>GONEY</wd:Legal_Last_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Middle_Name>KETHAN</wd:Legal_Middle_Name>
            <wd:Hire_Date>02/04/2019</wd:Hire_Date>
            <wd:Custom_Org_Dept wd:Descriptor="027 ELECTRICAL/LIGHTING">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01e59a4e80b3221117d0</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
            </wd:Custom_Org_Dept>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Full time">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e083484df07201c3ab266f6339407c00</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Full_time</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Pay_Rate_Type wd:Descriptor="Salary">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ee8dd6d421811a37d</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID">Salary</wd:ID>
            </wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
            <wd:Time_Type_Code>FS</wd:Time_Type_Code>
            <wd:Label_Line_1>SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Label_Line_1>
            <wd:Active_Status>1</wd:Active_Status>
        </wd:Associate_group>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
            <wd:Learning_Content_Title>PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:Learning_Content_Title>
            <wd:Registration_Status wd:Descriptor="Enrolled">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">cb6902eac8a110002327d007902323af</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Registration_Record_Status_ID">ENROLLED</wd:ID>
            </wd:Registration_Status>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Learning_Content wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b465a8da42a30000</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">MULTI_COURSE_TEMPLATE-6-1</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Content>
        <wd:Assignment_Status wd:Descriptor="Open">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">a9e125b224f310000c6071e412620120</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Assignment_Status_ID">OPEN</wd:ID>
        </wd:Assignment_Status>
        <wd:Required>0</wd:Required>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version assigned to RAJEEV KALASANI">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc079018b58dc7db2b070000</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment>
        <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="SRSFWE - SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01fb2bdcf60a7811b1e7</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">SRSFWE</wd:ID>
        </wd:Job_Profile>
        <wd:Job_Title>SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Job_Title>
        <wd:Associate_Manager wd:Descriptor="JUBIN JOSEPH">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">84d886702b650179290394d3f63ca203</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">126061787</wd:ID>
        </wd:Associate_Manager>
        <wd:Learning_Record_group>
            <wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record wd:Descriptor="RAJEEV KALASANI - PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b58dc7404bcd0001</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Enrollment_ID">LEARNING_ENROLLMENT-6-3</wd:ID>
            </wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record>
            <wd:Record_Start_Date>2022-07-12T06:54:27-07:00</wd:Record_Start_Date>
        </wd:Learning_Record_group>
        <wd:Associate_group>
            <wd:Associates_location wd:Descriptor="MARIETTA TECHNOLOGY CENTER, MARIETTA - 9119">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ae25e829c2211e5b3</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Location_ID">9119</wd:ID>
            </wd:Associates_location>
            <wd:Associate_ID>137317590</wd:Associate_ID>
            <wd:Legal_First_Name>RAJEEV</wd:Legal_First_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Last_Name>KALASANI</wd:Legal_Last_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Middle_Name>R</wd:Legal_Middle_Name>
            <wd:Hire_Date>02/25/2019</wd:Hire_Date>
            <wd:Custom_Org_Dept wd:Descriptor="027 ELECTRICAL/LIGHTING">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01e59a4e80b3221117d0</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
            </wd:Custom_Org_Dept>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Full time">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e083484df07201c3ab266f6339407c00</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Full_time</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Pay_Rate_Type wd:Descriptor="Salary">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ee8dd6d421811a37d</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID">Salary</wd:ID>
            </wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
            <wd:Time_Type_Code>FS</wd:Time_Type_Code>
            <wd:Label_Line_1>SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Label_Line_1>
            <wd:Active_Status>1</wd:Active_Status>
        </wd:Associate_group>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
            <wd:Learning_Content_Title>PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:Learning_Content_Title>
            <wd:Registration_Status wd:Descriptor="Enrolled">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">cb6902eac8a110002327d007902323af</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Registration_Record_Status_ID">ENROLLED</wd:ID>
            </wd:Registration_Status>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Learning_Content wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b465a8da42a30000</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">MULTI_COURSE_TEMPLATE-6-1</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Content>
        <wd:Assignment_Status wd:Descriptor="Open">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">a9e125b224f310000c6071e412620120</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Assignment_Status_ID">OPEN</wd:ID>
        </wd:Assignment_Status>
        <wd:Required>0</wd:Required>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment wd:Descriptor="PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version assigned to MADHU JANAKI">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc079018b58dcae038cf0002</wd:ID>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment>
        <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="SRSFWE - SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01fb2bdcf60a7811b1e7</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">SRSFWE</wd:ID>
        </wd:Job_Profile>
        <wd:Job_Title>SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Job_Title>
        <wd:Associate_Manager wd:Descriptor="JUBIN JOSEPH">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">84d886702b650179290394d3f63ca203</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">126061787</wd:ID>
        </wd:Associate_Manager>
        <wd:Learning_Record_group>
            <wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record wd:Descriptor="MADHU JANAKI - PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018b58dcae038cf0000</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Enrollment_ID">LEARNING_ENROLLMENT-6-4</wd:ID>
            </wd:Learning_Enrollment_Record>
            <wd:Record_Start_Date>2022-07-12T06:54:27-07:00</wd:Record_Start_Date>
        </wd:Learning_Record_group>
        <wd:Associate_group>
            <wd:Associates_location wd:Descriptor="MARIETTA TECHNOLOGY CENTER, MARIETTA - 9119">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ae25e829c2211e5b3</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Location_ID">9119</wd:ID>
            </wd:Associates_location>
            <wd:Associate_ID>137189544</wd:Associate_ID>
            <wd:Legal_First_Name>MADHU</wd:Legal_First_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Last_Name>JANAKI</wd:Legal_Last_Name>
            <wd:Hire_Date>12/03/2018</wd:Hire_Date>
            <wd:Custom_Org_Dept wd:Descriptor="027 ELECTRICAL/LIGHTING">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd01e59a4e80b3221117d0</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">027</wd:ID>
            </wd:Custom_Org_Dept>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Full time">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e083484df07201c3ab266f6339407c00</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Full_time</wd:ID>
            </wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Pay_Rate_Type wd:Descriptor="Salary">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3e82bdec28fd018ee8dd6d421811a37d</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID">Salary</wd:ID>
            </wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
            <wd:Time_Type_Code>FS</wd:Time_Type_Code>
            <wd:Label_Line_1>SR SOFTWARE ENGINEER</wd:Label_Line_1>
            <wd:Active_Status>1</wd:Active_Status>
        </wd:Associate_group>
        <wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
            <wd:Learning_Content_Title>PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version</wd:Learning_Content_Title>
            <wd:Registration_Status wd:Descriptor="Enrolled">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">cb6902eac8a110002327d007902323af</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Registration_Record_Status_ID">ENROLLED</wd:ID>
            </wd:Registration_Status>
        </wd:Learning_Enrollment_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

The expected output is

reportloaddate,storenumber,coursenumbername,totalregistrations,countincomplete,
08/23/2022,MARIETTA TECHNOLOGY CENTER, MARIETTA - 9119,PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version,4,3

But the output I m getting

08/23/2022,MARIETTA TECHNOLOGY CENTER, MARIETTA - 9119,PPF Paula's Course on Cats US Version,4,1

The countincomplete column is not fetching correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<xsl:variable name="Incompletecount" select="count(wd:Assignment_Status/@wd:Descriptor != 'Completed')"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="Incompletecount" select="count(//wd:Assignment_Status[@wd:Descriptor != 'Completed'])"/>
```

Your attribute count condition must be wrapped inside brackets like this:
"[condition != 'expression']"